# AngularJS 1.6 routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-1.6

I am trying to create my first angular app. But its not working at all. I have no idea what's the problem. I checked the console, but there's no erros.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>Test angular</h1>
  <a href="#/">Main</a>
  <a href="#sec">Second</a>
  <a href="#th">Third</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
      templateUrl : "main.html"
  })
  .when("/sec", {
      templateUrl : "sec.html"
  })
  .when("/th", {
      templateUrl : "th.html"
  });
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: there are no erros in the console :/

Comment: Do all resources resolve properly? Do you see your template when you request you http://applicationurl/main.html?

Comment: Im running on local server.

Comment: @Jaroen yes i see my template when i request to

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Routes in Angular 1.6 changed from `#/myUrl` to `#!/myUrl`

You should change your ref to:

```
<a href="#!/">Main</a>
<a href="#!/sec">Second</a>
<a href="#!/th">Third</a>
```

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41226167/4927984) if you want to remove this prefix.

Comment: @John Sparwasser:  Thanks. Worked for me too for 1.6.4/angular.min.js...

Comment: Perfect answer !! @Mistalis great solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding $locationProvider to your script

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that you didn't include the `$routeProvider` properly, Here's the working routing code:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
      templateUrl : "main.html"
  })
  .when("/sec", {
      templateUrl : "sec.html"
  })
  .when("/th", {
      templateUrl : "th.html"
  });
}]);
```

Comment: is the website hosted on a local server? If not, then that's the reason why it's not working

Comment: Yes, it is hosted on local server.

Comment: Try posting a jsFiddle with your website so that I can check why this problem is occurring

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is working

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html'
    })
    .when('/service', {
        templateUrl: 'service.html'
    });}]);
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to fix your href attributes:

The correct way is:

```
<a href="#/">Main</a>
<a href="#/sec">Second</a>
<a href="#/th">Third</a>
```