# URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, hashbang, angularjs-1.6

My URLs on an AngularJS project have changed from `localhost:3000/admin#/` to `localhost:3000/admin#!/` since the last time I worked on my project...

Nothing found on the web, does someone know what this is ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is new from AngularJS 1.6, which added a new hash prefix.

> Due to [aa077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8), the default hash-prefix used for `$location` hash-bang
>   URLs has changed from the empty string (`''`) to the bang (`'!'`). If your
>   application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that
>   do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own
>   hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a `!` prefix. For
>   example, rather than `mydomain.com/#/a/b/c` the URL will become
>   `mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c`.

[Source here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8) for more information.

---

*If you want to remove this prefix, add this code to your config:*

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Answer (score 11):

Everyone is proposing to remove the prefix, but you could also simply add a `!` to client-side URLs (if not using HTML5 mode, which you probably do if you're here).

So in your **client-side** files, update URLS like this:

`#/foo/bar` > `#!/foo/bar`

Comment: How can I read that default prefix so I can use some smart code to add this prefix to URLs if needed?

Answer (score 6):

In Angular 1.6.0, the default hashPrefix has been changed to `!`.
See the [related commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52) and the [changelog entry](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#location-due-to).

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, angular 1.6 added a hashtag in this form: http://localhost:52245/#/callback#code=BD55C7FD4F129A9CAC1506E225EF9149

But I needed it in this form:
http://localhost:52245/callback#code=BD55C7FD4F129A9CAC1506E225EF9149

I spent some days until find the solution. So added this configuration in the frondEnd web.config, in <system.webServer> section:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*"/>
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

After that, all work ok

Comment: I think using the `#` to declare route parameters looks a bit awkward. You might want to use a more common route format like `/callback/BD55C7FD4F129A9CAC1506E225EF9149` or `/callback?code=BD55C7FD4F129A9CAC1506E225EF9149`
Also here's a great SO answer on different ways to pass parameters into AngularJS routes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647714/5567941