# AngularJS All slashes in URL changed to %2F

Tags: angularjs, laravel, href, angularjs-1.6

I'm having a massive problem with AngularJS routing.

Up until recently everything has been fine with the following route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/album/:albumId', {
    controller: 'albumPageController',
    templateUrl: 'views/album.html'
});
```

and using the href:

```
<a href="/#/album/{{album.id}}">Link</a>
```

However, now all of the slashes are being encoded into `%2F`.

So when I click the link, or type `localhost:8000/#/album/1` into the browser, the URL is changed to:

> http://localhost:8000/#%2Falbum%2F1

I've tried several things to correct this:

Using ng-href instead of href, 
Not using the first / (ie `href="#/album/{{album.id}}"`)
Running the app in Homestead localhost (Laravel's linux vagrant machine) instead of localhost on Windows 10

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've also tried using the full URL in the href (and ng-href), no changes

Comment: are using it in html5mode?

Comment: $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`%2F` is the [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for the forward-slash `/` character.

This problem is related to the fact that AngularJS 1.6 has changed the default for hash-bang urls in the `$location` service.

To revert to the previous behavior:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

For more information, see [SO: angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working).

Comment: I've reviewed several threads about this, and this seems to be the only answer.

Answer (score 26):

The most simple solution is to add a `!` to client-side URLs (if not using HTML5 mode, which you probably do if you're here).

Client-side, update URLS like this:

`#/foo/bar` > `#!/foo/bar`

And since you keep the `#`, there is **no** issue of conflict with server-side routing. Everyone happy.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me but... what does exactly `!` does?

Comment: The `!#` (previously only `#`) is a convention defined by Angular to separate server-side routing from client-side routing. For instance, starting with this adress `foo.com/app#!/home`, if you go to URL `foo.com/app#!/profile`, you will not see a page reload. It is the Angular app (running in your browser so client-side), that will update the contents from the `home` page to the `profile` page, because you've changed the URL **after** the `#!`. Instead, if you go to `foo.com/otherstuff`, you are before the `#!` so you will request the server with the new page `otherstuff`

Answer (score 10):

A bit late to the party but adding a '!' to your URLs will work just fine. This bothered me for a bit as well. This is a change in the latest AngularJS 1.6.x and I read somewhere that Google requires SPAs to have that '!' after the hash. As a result my routes look as they should but my navigation makes sure I add '!' in my references. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/page3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/page4">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps you.

Regards!

Comment: and i was following the many other suggestions which mentioned using #/page2. Thanks for the !.

Answer (score 6):

For me, i fixed the problem :

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: false,
    requireBase: true
  });
});

<a href="#/mylink/"> <span>MyLink</span></a>
```

Which give : http://blablabla.co:8888/blabla#/mylink/

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

slash encoding can be disabled:

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('SlashFix', {
  raw:    true,
});


$stateProvider
      .state('content',{
       url: '/{slug:SlashFix}'
       ...

      })
```

as described here https://www.coditty.com/code/angular-ui-router-replacing-slash-with-2f-quick-fix

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hash symbol from the link, since you are using html5mode you do not need a hash symbol for routing

```
<a href="/#/album/{{album.id}}">Link</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="/album/{{album.id}}">Link</a>
```

Comment: Just tried that - It did technically solve the issue of not encoding the slashes, but at the end of the day I need the # there (otherwise Laravel will deal with the route /album/1 and give a 404, as it's an SPA)

Comment: Can you try with the # but set html5mode to false and requireBase to true?