# /#/ is getting converted to /#!#%2F

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, ngroute

I had a project that I developed using `angularjs`. I was using `npm` for package management.
I was able to access my web application in browser with below url

```
http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/#/home
```

In index.html I had following code portion

```
<div id="main" data-ui-view ></div>
```

I was using `ng-router` to add content in `#main` div.
When I tried to get my project work after some time on different computer, it doesn't work. I cloned my project, **ran npm commands to get all libraries**. Then when I try to access application with above url, It gets converted to below url

```
http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/#!#%2Fhome
```

And nothing is loaded into my index.html file's `#main` div. There is no error being shown in browser's console.

Do anybody know why it is happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will address the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272314/angular-all-slashes-in-url-changed-to-2f#answer-41273403

Comment: Thanks @ChrisT, That answer solved my problem.