# issue getting data of other page in a single page application using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

This my app.js,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).when('/detail',{
        templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
        controller: 'detailCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

});

myApp.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.message ="Welcome to your Home Page"
});

myApp.controller('detailCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.message ="Name: Manish"
});
```

This is index.html page,

```
    <html >
      <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Try It Out</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
      </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl" style="text-align: center;">
        <span ><a href="/">{{message}}</a></span><br>

        <a href="#/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#/detail">Details</a>

        <br><br>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <h4>copyright 2017</h4>
      </body>
   </html>
```

this is my home.html

```
<h3>Home</h3><br>
 {{message}}
```

same in details.html

```
<h3>Details</h3><br>
 {{message}}
```

problem is when i run it on server its going to home page at first.but when i click on details..its not showing message of Details.html.
and main problem is with URL...clicking on Details link..

```
http://localhost:7675/AngularJSinglePage/#!/#%2Fdetail
```

As u can notice  "!/#%2F" this comes in between..don't know from where,it should come like this

```
http://localhost:7675/AngularJSinglePage/#/detail
```

Any one faced same problem? Help me out, I am trying to learn SPA using AngularJS?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `#` before the `/` ? in your `<a href `

Comment: Yup i did try removing "#" before "/" . then when i click on "Details" achor link ,then URL comes like this
(http://localhost:7675/detail)  but it should be like (http://localhost:7675/AngularJSinglePage/detaul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273403 :)

In addition you do not have a spaController in your app.js which is referenced in your

Comment: Thanks it worked.
I just added "!" after hash..
<a href="#!/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#!/detail">Details</a>