# Removing # prefix from an AngularJS site without breaking links

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-routing, angularjs-ng-route

I have an AngularJS website based on Firebase.
I have managed to remove the `#` prefix and reqrite urls like `/#/home` to `/home`, 
using the code below:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
      });
    }
  }])
```

however, the existing anchors create problems. When I click on `<a href="#/faq">FAQ</a>`, it takes me to `/home#%2Ffaq`
Of course, I can change the `href` of some anchors, but do not see that as a solution, as there might be some links somewhere that remain unchanged and get broken.

How do I resolve this issue without breaking the existing links?

Comment: @georgeawg, that's a different problem. My problem is not with the `%2F` part, but the fact that `#/xxx` is appended to the current location e.g. `/home`, because of the migration from html4 to html5. My existing links still use `#/xxx` format, which will not work after enabling html5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS All slashes in URL changed to %2F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272314/angularjs-all-slashes-in-url-changed-to-2f).