# Routing not working on Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to work out a simple example for the angular routing but its not working.  home,courses and students links are not working

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Demo">
<head>
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body >

    <table style="font-family: Arial"> 
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2" class="header"> <h1> WebSite Header </h1> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="leftMenu"> 
                    <a href="#/home">Home</a> 
                    <a href="#/courses">Courses</a> 
                    <a href="#/students">Students</a> </td> 
            <td class="mainContent"> 
                <ng-view></ng-view> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2" class="footer"> <b>Website Footer</b> </td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**script2.js**

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"]) 
        .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) { 
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider 
                .when("/home", {
                     templateUrl: "Templates/home.html", 
                     controller: "homeController" }) 
                .when("/courses", { 
                    templateUrl: "Templates/courses.html", 
                    controller: "coursesController" }) 
                .when("/students", { 
                    templateUrl: "Templates/students.html", 
                    controller: "studentsController" }) }) 
        .controller("homeController", function ($scope) { 
            $scope.message = "Home Page"; }) 
        .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) { 
            $scope.message = "Courses Page"; }) 
        .controller("studentsController", function ($scope) { 
            $scope.message = "Students Page"; 
    })
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>{{ message }}</h1> 
<h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Any help on this would  be much appreciated

Comment: It has problem with 
`  
 <td class="leftMenu"> 
                    <a href="#/home">Home</a> 
                    <a href="#/courses">Courses</a> 
                    <a href="#/students">Students</a> </td>
 ` You should try <a> tag like 
`
<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>`

Comment: @bhoomikhanapara Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: instead of using '#/home' try '#home'

Comment: Thanks @bhoomikhanapara i changed code as per your suggestion but  not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your routing:

```
<a href="#!/home">Home</a> 
<a href="#!/courses">Courses</a> 
<a href="#!/students">Students</a>
```

The routing changed in version 1.6.0 (?) and so you have to use hash-bang notation now. You could change it from this by adding this code around where you have your html5Mode:

```
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: I do not understand the symbol '!' in Anchor's href="" attribute.

Comment: Take a look at this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286031/angular-hash-versus-hashbang it goes over it

Answer (score 1):

Try this way: Firstly remove `#` from href.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Demo">
<head>
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body >

    <table style="font-family: Arial"> 
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2" class="header"> <h1> WebSite Header </h1> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="leftMenu"> 
                    <a href ng-click="redirectToHome()">Home</a> 
                    <a href ng-click="redirectToCourse()">Courses</a> 
                    <a href ng-click="redirectToStudent()">Students</a> </td> 
            <td class="mainContent"> 
                <ng-view></ng-view> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2" class="footer"> <b>Website Footer</b> </td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And JS Code:

```
  var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"]) 
                .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) { 
                     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                    $routeProvider 
                        .when("/home", {
                             templateUrl: "Templates/home.html", 
                             controller: "homeController" }) 
                        .when("/courses", { 
                            templateUrl: "Templates/courses.html", 
                            controller: "coursesController" }) 
                        .when("/students", { 
                            templateUrl: "Templates/students.html", 
                            controller: "studentsController" }) })
                .run(function($rootScope,$location){
    $rootScope.redirectToHome=function(){
    $location.path('\home');
    }
    $rootScope.redirectToCourse=function(){
    $location.path('\courses');
    }
    $rootScope.redirectToStudent=function(){
    $location.path('\students');
    }
                    })
                .controller("homeController", function ($scope) { 
                    $scope.message = "Home Page"; }) 
                .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) { 
                    $scope.message = "Courses Page"; }) 
                .controller("studentsController", function ($scope) { 
                    $scope.message = "Students Page"; 
            })
```