# Angular Route - Extra # in URL

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-1.6

Learning some Angular - and I'm stuck on routing

Here is my angular config

```
var meanApp = angular.module('carz', ['ngRoute']);


meanApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/red', {
            templateUrl: 'red.html',
            controller: 'redCtrl'
        });
});
```

Here is are my links

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#red">Red</a>
```

When I load up my node app I am directed to

```
http://localhost:8080/#!/
```

And I get my angular controller working as expected within the `ng-view` tags

But I cannot switch from one controller to the other using the links above.

**If I select the red tag my URL adds an extra # becoming**

```
http://localhost:8080/#!/#red
```

Note if I manually change to

```
http://localhost:8080/#!/red
```

My controller changes and it works so why am I getting the extra #

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question can be helpful for you, Thanks.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Comment: <a href="#!/red">Red</a>. It should work

Comment: @ArpitMeena I tried that prior to posting the question and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since AngularJS 1.6 there is a breaking change in routing:

> The hash-prefix for $location hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string "" to the bang "!".

(See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Solution:

either start using #! Instead of #
OR set up $locationProvider to accept just using #, like this:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks - I might stick with ui-router then ? thoughts ?

Comment: DogCoffee: We were using ui-router in the app we discovered the problem, so that might not help ;)

Comment: Cheers - so far so good with ui-router. Also the $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); fixes the problem with ngRoute.