# angular route keeps getting encoded

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am relative new to angular and tried to create a new webapp with a yeoman generator. All good but then I try to add a new route,

```
angular
.module('App', [
    'ngRoute'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/reset', {
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'test'
        })
});
```

However when I try to access the route like:

```
http://localhost:8081/#/reset
```

It keeps getting replaced with:

```
http://localhost:8081/#!#%2Freset
```

Comment: Why do you try to access `http://localhost:8081/#/reset` shouldn't it be `http://localhost:8081/#/test`?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error. The route is /reset and I access it with http://localhost:8081/#/reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41919388/4020932) and see if it solves your problem. It looks like you may need to add `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` to the route config.

Comment: Thanks a lot, at the time you posted I've also found an answer