# angular routing not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes

It seems that by asking this question, I am just beating a dead horse, but I have been through all the posts that I could find and still could not find an answer. I (and even a colleague) have spent countless hours trying to solve what seems to be a relatively basic concept. So , can I please get some help with my angularjs routing

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="foodApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>What Do I Eat</title>

    <link href="/app/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="/app/js/controllers/ExistingRestaurantController.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/controllers/NewExperienceController.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/controllers/NewRestaurantController.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/controllers/indexController.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/services/RestaurantData.Service.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
        <h1>What Do I Eat</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#/myRest">My Restaurants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/addRest">Add Restaurant</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/addExp">Add Experience</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ng-view></ng-view>

    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid">
        whatever i want
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';

var foodApp = angular.module('foodApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

foodApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/myRest',
            {
                templateUrl: '/templates/ExistingRestaurant.html',
                controller: 'ExistingRestaurantController'
            })
            .when('/addExp',
            {
                templateUrl: '/templates/NewExperience.html',
                controller: 'NewExperienceController'
            })
            .when('/addRest',
            {
                templateUrl: '/templates/NewRestaurant.html',
                controller: 'NewRestaurantController'
            });
    }
]);
```

ExistingRetaurantController.js

```
'use strict';

foodApp.controller('ExistingRestaurantController',
    function ExistingRestaurantController($scope) {

        $scope.restaurant = {
            name: 'Cheesecake Factory',
            food: 'Cheesecake',
            price: 6.95
        }
    }
);
```

ExistingRestaurant.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Existing Page!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Should have nothing to do with Visual Studio. Are you working with the .NET MVC framework? If so, it uses the routing from the `RouteConfig.cs` file. From my experience, angular routing and the .NET MVC routing do not play nicely together - although I would imagine any two routing engines pitted against each other would have similar problems

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: @mhodges no, I started with a blank site. I added the VS 2015 for a reference to the WebServer as that was a topic on many of the other closely related questions.

Comment: Try specifying `index.html` explictly in the url - if you haven't already, just thinking VS won't put it in by default if there are no default routes set up.

Comment: Also add a default route to your angular routing using `.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/myRest" });` or similar.

Comment: And... make note that the routes are case sensitive unless you add the `caseInsensitiveMatch: true` property to your routes - my guess is it's this one, the cause of many a headache!.

Comment: @MatthewCawley this is my starting Url : http://localhost:2421/app/index.html and strangely when i click a one of my links, this is the new Url: http://localhost:2421/app/index.html#!#%2FmyRest but absolutely nothing happens

Comment: @MatthewCawley that is exactly how my URL looks. Is what is in the index.html (<li><a href="#/myRest">My Restaurants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/addRest">Add Restaurant</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/addExp">Add Experience</a></li>) not what you are looking for?

Comment: Okay thanks, and try one of those links without the hash. `<li><a href="/myRest">My Restaurants</a></li>`

Comment: @MatthewCawley been way up and down that road, but tried again, and still a no go

Comment: Okay, it's a tough one, my last attempt, add `<base href="/app/">` to your head tag!?

Comment: Index.html would normally be outside of the app folder by the way, whereas yours appears to be nested within it!?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the project structure. Index.html appears to be nested within app. I thought the easiest fix was to move index.html to the root of the project. So with a folder structure of:

[image]

I was able to getting working as follows..

In **Index.html**,  I changed the links to be `#!/` (hash-bang):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="foodApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>What Do I Eat</title>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="/app/js/controllers/ExistingRestaurantController.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/controllers/NewExperienceController.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/controllers/NewRestaurantController.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!/myRest">My Restaurants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/addRest">Add Restaurant</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/addExp">Add Experience</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in **app.js** I added the `$locationProvider` and set the hash-prefix to `!`. *(I don't know why it's called hashPrefix because I always think it's a suffix, given that it comes after the hash, but I can live with it.)*

```
'use strict';

var foodApp = angular.module('foodApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

foodApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");

        $routeProvider
            .when('/myRest',
            {
                templateUrl: '/app/templates/ExistingRestaurant.html',
                controller: 'ExistingRestaurantController'
            })
            .when('/addExp',
            {
                templateUrl: '/app/templates/NewExperience.html',
                controller: 'NewExperienceController'
            })
            .when('/addRest',
            {
                templateUrl: '/app/templates/NewRestaurant.html',
                controller: 'NewRestaurantController'
            });
    }
]);
```

Your start path then becomes:

```
http://localhost:63317/index.html
```

and changes to the following when clicking the links:

```
http://localhost:63317/index.html#!/myRest
http://localhost:63317/index.html#!/addRest
http://localhost:63317/index.html#!/addExp
```

Comment: You could also set `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` (empty string) and keep your links as `#/`, there is another thread on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328840/angular-route-extra-in-url

Comment: I tried everything there and nothing worked, however, I did find my answer and posted it. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I tried again and, and the $locationProvider.hashPrefix( '  ' ); is what actually worked for version 1.6.1. thank you again!

Comment: Yes I since realised myself that this is a problem tied to version 1.6 it's caught a few people out - including me! Pleased it's sorted anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well after 4 days of searching, I finally figured out my own answer. I was using angular version 1.6.1. The moment I rolled it back to 1.2.1, everything worked fine. I shall continue to research to figure out best routing practices.

Comment: Angular >1.6.x is significantly different from <1.5.x, so probably angular 1.5 will also work for you (1.2 is pretty old)

Comment: When I posted this, i hadn't tried running through the versions yet. I am currently trying to find a solution for >1.6.x. I have a few leads and will attempt them later this evening. Will keep this thread updated as I discover.

Comment: appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling your angular version back until it works.

Comment: exactly what i did.. and worked perfectly, thank you!