# hashtag (#) on urls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, url, google-analytics

I am using angularjs framework in my website.
I have a problem with urls! There is # in urls in Google analytics
[image]

I am using Html5Mode in my config.js

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, $analyticsProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
    $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true); /* Records pages that don't use $state or $route */
    $analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true); /* Records full path */
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

it is some part of my routes.js:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', "$routeProvider",
function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    var modulesPath = 'modules/';
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
        title: '',
        templateUrl: modulesPath + "site/views/index.html",
        access: {
            requiredLogin: false
        }
    }).when("/index", {
        redirectTo: "/",
        access: {
            requiredLogin: false
        }
    }).when("/home", {
        redirectTo: "/",
        access: {
            requiredLogin: false
        }
    }).when("/terms", {
        title: 'Terms and Conditions',
        templateUrl: modulesPath + "terms/views/index.html",
        access: {
            requiredLogin: false
        }
```

I tried several ways like adding $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

plase help me to fix it
thank you

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.6?

Comment: yes @Mistalis, is there any problem with this version?

Comment: The route system has changed a bit. Take a look to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41226167/4927984) here.

Comment: I changed it to $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); but I have the problem like before in google analytics @Mistalis

Comment: I don't get it. What's seems to be the issue? GA should work perfectly fine, despite the hash sign in the URLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)