# angular-route1.6.1 does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

thank u for looking!
Here's my question.

```
[app.html]
...
<custom />
...
<script>
...
app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/checkout", {
        templateUrl: "views/checkoutSummary.html",
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/products", {
        templateUrl: "views/productList.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: "/views/productList.html",
    })
}])
...
</script>
```

The directive for "custom" is here:

```
<div class="navbar-right">
    <div class="navbar-text">
        <b>购物车：</b>
        {{itemCount()}} 个商品,
        {{total() | currency}}
    </div>
    <a href="#/checkout" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">结算</a>
</div>
```

When I click element "a",the href in my browser is:

`http://localhost:3000/app.html#!#%2Fcheckout`

and the `$location.hash()` is `/checkout`

Actually, the correct href should be:

`http://localhost:3000/app.html#!/checkout`

or

`http://localhost:3000/app.html#!%2Fcheckout`

Why that the program add the "#" behind the "!"?

Tx and Happy Chinese New Year!

Comment: try, `<a href="#checkout" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">结算</a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tx! I have solve it!
The reason is in version 1.6.1 the route rule has been changed.
The correct way to write the url is:

`href="#!/checkout"`

Annother way to sovle this problem:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

follow:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52