# How to define links to angular routes in hashbang mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

What is the right way to define links to angular routes in hashbang (non-HTML5) mode?

Suppose that I have the following nav. bar:

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#!/first">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/second">Second</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#!/" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

It works but I have the following questions in mind:

- I saw a lot of articles where authors do the same thing via `/first` or `#/first` instead of `#!/first` but it doesn't work for me for some reason (I guess that's because I'm using `#!` as a hashstring but I don't know why there's so many examples with `#/first` instead of `#!/first` if the latter is the default one)
- Is it ok to define `logout` action this way?

  ```
  <li><a href="#!/" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  ```

Because it seems a little bit ugly for me.

Comment: angular routes were changed in 1.6.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash-bang synthax is [new from Angular 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6/41226167#41226167). This release is still new, it may explain why you don't see many articles with the hash-bang routing.

Anyway, from this line:

```
<li><a href="#!/" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
```

You can move the redirection to the `logout()` function:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    ...
    $location.url('/home');
}
```

---

*Don't forget to inject [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).*

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm actually doing. So it's totally ok, right? And what about the other question?

Comment: @FrozenHeart In my opinion, it is the cleanest way. I've updated my answer about the `#!/` synthax, hope it helps! :)

Comment: Are you sure that location.url argument should have a hashbang string? It works w/o it as well

Comment: @FrozenHeart My bad, you can use `'/home'` instead. Fixed!