# Redirect URLs without hashbang to URLs with hashbang using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, hashbang

Since upgrading to AngularJS 1.6, hashbangs are defaulted.

How would I redirect formerly distributed URLs to transform to a version with the hashbang?

For example `www.myu.rl/#/hello/` would then become `www.myu.rl/#!/hello`

Currently it navigates to `www.myu.rl/#!#%2F/hello`, which redirects to the home page.

Comment: You can use interceptors for this: https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/

Comment: @MikeCheel doesn't look like it. `config.url` doesn't contain the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the hash-bang mode (`#!/`), then set your hash-prefix to:

```
$location.hashPrefix('!');
```

If you would like to go back to the good ol' days, see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6/41226167#41226167).

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. URL `myu.rl/#/hello` doesn't become `myu.rl/#!/hello`, but redirects to the home page by going to `myu.rl/#!#%2Fhello`.

Comment: @Tom Could you try `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` instead?

Comment: that's what I tried. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Appreciate it anyways.