# trying to load localhost/ but shows //localhost/#!/ , localhost/#!/#%2Flogin, localhost/#!/#%2Fregister

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

i am trying to make a angular webpage. but when i am load the localhost it shows me //localhost/#!/ ,  localhost/#!/#%2Flogin, localhost/#!/#%2Fregister. please give me solution.

```js
angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])

 .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/',{
  templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
 })
 .when('/login',{
  templateUrl: 'view/login.html'
 })
 .when('/register',{
  templateUrl: 'view/register.html'
 })
 .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <title>School App</title>
</head>
<body class="container">
<header id="header" class="nav navbar-header nav-justified">
 <legend class="nav navbar-brand"><a href="#/" >School App</a></legend>
 <nav class="nav navbar nav-justified navbar-form">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="nav navbar-default navbar-link"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li class="nav navbar-default navbar-link"><a href="#/login">login</a></li>
   <li class="nav navbar-default navbar-link"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header><!-- /header -->
<main ng-view>
 
</main>

<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap.css">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Removing hash in angular app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol#answer-39005642