# Routing issue in Angular (happening a "!" in URL)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

I'm using Angular `ngRoute`.

When I'm trying to route to another page, it is not redirecting in URL. It shows as `http://localhost:58317/#!#%2Fstudents`

**myApp.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['googlechart', 'ngRoute'])
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Hello Angular.....";
})

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        templateUrl: '/Home/part1',
        controller: 'routeDemoFirstController'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/Home/part2',
        controller: 'routeDemoSecondController'
    }).
     when('/students', {
         templateUrl: '/Home/part2',
         controller: 'routeDemoSecondController'
     })
})
```

**Index.cshtml**
This is my .cshtml code Here i write anchor tag

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <a href="/#/home">Home</a>
        <a href="#/contact">Courses</a>
        <a href="#/students">Students</a>
    </div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the hash-bang prefix:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
```

It signicates that your URL should be:

```
<a href="#!/home">Home</a>
```

---

If you want to remove the `!` from the URL (*you can also remove the `#`*), you can check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6/41226167#41226167)**.

Comment: Thank you soo much Dear Mistails

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
```

Make changes to html

```
<div class="row">
        <div>
            <a ng-href="#!/home">Home</a>
            <a ng-href="#!/contact">Courses</a>
            <a ng-href="#!/students">Students</a>
        </div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```