# Routing problems with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-1.6

I don't understand why my routing doesn't work, the "otherwise" case is working, but when I click in one of the menu the routing doesn't automatically load the relative page. 
Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong with my code please?

This is the code relative to the routing part:

```
var myColors = angular.module('myFirstModule', ['ngRoute']);
myColors.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .when('/directory', {
      templateUrl: 'directory.html',
      controller: 'myFirstModule'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/directory'
    });
}]);
```

Here it is the HTML div where I put the links:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#/directory">Directory</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [<kbd>**Plunker**</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/DZZxRScx8jU7IeaY6Pm3?p=preview) of my full code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong controller name and also as @Mistalis told you have to include `#!` in your href. If you want to remove the ! just use `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` in your config. Then you can use your href without `!`

**JS**

```
var myColors = angular.module('myFirstModule', ['ngRoute']);
myColors.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .when('/directory', {
      templateUrl: 'directory.html',
      controller: 'myFirstController' //use your controller name here
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/directory'
    });
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!/home">Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/directory">Directory</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Working Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/GAob2u4MdnzXXltTZMg2?p=preview

Comment: I'm new to AngularJS, do you have any good tutorial/example where I can learn it better? Moreover, as you see, if I make some changes in the directory page and then click to go in another page, after returning back, all the changes are deleted, there is any way to save the changes ? Thanks.

Comment: You can find some tutorials here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info . Better is go to  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts and learn. If you need the data to persist, you should use localstorage.

Answer (score 2):

[Since you are using AngularJS 1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8), you need to add a `!` is your href routing.
Eg: `href="#/home"` becomes `href="#!/home"`.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/directory">Directory</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to remove this prefix, see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6/41226167#41226167).