# Single-SPA AngularJS break routing of parent app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, single-page-application

Tried to build something using [Single-Spa](https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa) and faced with problem adding to app AngularJS. Angular2 and ReactJs working perfect but if add AngularJS and tried to use url for this app - it breaks a url of parent app.
for example link was:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/app  => http://localhost:8080/#!#%2Fapp
```

After it app of AngularJS not working at all.
I use for bundling webpack and added application exactly like in examples of Single-Spa. Maybe someone has ideas how to fix it?

Comment: can you change your hash-bang with [`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('#');`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)?

Comment: Tried - it's not help at all.

Answer (score 1):

on owners repo I've got answer:
 Add $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); into your route configuration 
and everything will start to work.