# How to remove # after a doamin

Tags: angularjs, apache

I have a website lets say http://example.com/ .The subpages on the websites should ideally show-up as example.com/page1 but the way my page shows up is example.com/#/page1

Is there a way to remove the "#" to make the link simple to share with others.

The theme used was this: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-2-angular

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes the `#` harder to share the link?

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6